# Can anyone recommend a concurrent, real-time diagramming/flowchart collaboration tool?

Tags: concurrency, uml, class-diagram, diagramming

I'm looking to work with others to quickly build a rather large class flow diagram that may or may not be strict UML. Can anyone recommend a networked, concurrent collaboration tool for such a task? Price is not an issue, but the target system must be Windows.

Surely someone must have done something like this in the past.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DabbleBoard](http://dabbleboard.com/) has an online diagramming tool that may do what you want.  It should work on Windows, although it is a web-based and fairly low-level.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how concurrent you need it, but [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com) have just introduced a 'drawing' document type, which is basically a stencil based system like visio.  It includes flowchart elements, and of course can be shared.